# VB.NET Picturebox Transparency?

Tags: vb.net, image, transparency, vb.net-2010, picturebox

I am creating a program which allows the user to select from a number of seats (whch are pictureboxes) to reserve the seats they want for an upcoming play. But this requires my layout to be compact and require some of the images to overap each other. My images that i am using are transparent .PNG's, but when one picture box overlaps another it still cuts the one. Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks.

Coding language: VB.NET in microsoft visual studio 2010

Problem:

[image]

Comment: Please include some code in your question, i.e. how the drawing is being done on the form.

Comment: How is that Relevant? This is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Code is always relevant to the question if the question is tagged with its language tag (VB.NET in this case). Even if you have a list of picture boxes, the answer depends on whether they are static or dynamically drawn on the form.

Comment: Without knowing how you are handling the drawing, how should we find the error?

Comment: pictureboxes never show the contents of the picturebox "behind" them ever - overlapped or not, transparent or not.  this is because what is behind every picturebox is the FORM (always).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls in WinForms don't handle transparency well. They fake it by drawing the underlying form on themselves, but this does not include other controls.

Two possibilities:

- Consider switching to WPF instead of WinForms.
- Draw the images in one bitmap and display it in one large picturebox.

  Without knowing how your code looks like. Consider a small image of a seat as `seat.png` in the application directory. Also consider that `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` define how many seats there are per row and how many rows there are. Adjust the `BmpOut` size accordingly.

  ```
  Dim BmpOut as New Bitmap(640,480)
  Using SeatImage as New Bitmap("seat.png")
    Using g as Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BmpOut)
       For x = 0 To ColumnCount - 1
          For y = 0 To RowCount - 1
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(SeatImage, x*SeatImage.Width, y*SeatImage.height)
          Next y
       Next x
    End Using
  End Using
  If Picturebox1.image IsNot Nothing then Picturebox1.Image.Dispose()
  Picturebox1.Image = bmpout
  ```

This should use the transparency of the PNG correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your method of drawing (you don't even need transparency for that), the easiest method would probably be reversing the order of drawing, i.e. draw bottom rows first.

Comment: But then the tops will be cut off each image, i can't believe that there is no way around a problem as simple as this :/

Comment: @user3756400: I may be wrong, but I think your "top" is just background, which is the same as your form, so it does not matter if it gets covered or not. A way around the actual "problem" depends on your current implementation.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but i think i have found an alternate, the images wont have to overlap if i use the "stretch" image format, so i might just use that

Comment: @user3756400: Should work, but may look weird, depending on interpolation method used, like same border width being 1 or 2px depending on image coordinates. Or just look blurry. Image stretch should be used as last resort. In your case, for example, you may redraw your images to be shorter, or just add more space between them.